# Textarea and monospace fonts

Tags: textarea, rows

In case cols textarea [attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-cols-TEXTAREA) "specifies the visible width in average character widths", why it doesn't mean, in fact, that if one uses monospace font, he'll get exactly as many letters to fit textarea rect, as it actually defined in cols?

**upd:** 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case of monospace, you should get exactly that much. Depending on the font however, spacing between two glyphs can be relevant.

Comment: Let me be more precise - hope, this this picture will help - http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5601/shabunc.1/0_63947_190f77ce_orig

Answer (score 1):

Works for me in Firefox 3.6.12/Linux and w3m 0.5.1.

[image: screenshot]

and

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: hm, very interesting. seems like i don't keep in mind some additional data to see the whole picture.